# LabVIEW driver - Bertan 225 - HV won't turn on

Tags: labview, visa

I'm trying to use the [Bertan 225 driver](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=E3B19B3E9635659CE034080020E74861). However, using the driver I cannot turn on the voltage (it does not produce any errors and the code it puts out seems to match the [user manual](http://www.spellmanhv.com/~/media/Files/Products/225.ashx)).

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or any ideas?

I can put the codes in

```
L00.500K
L1.0000M
OC1OE1OE2
SE1SC1
P0.05000K
```

And I can turn the instrument to local and it goes to 50 V (0.05 kV). Then I can put in

```
L00.500K
L1.0000M
OC1OE1OE2
SE1SC1
P0.10000K
```

And I can turn the instrument to local and it goes to 100 V (0.1 kV).

Comment: A few ways to narrow it down: Does Bertan provide any reference examples in C or Python for communicating with their instrument? If so, do you observe the same problem? You said, _"the code it puts out seems to match the user manual"_; how did you confirm the message contents: was it via [I/O Trace](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/282C5D41E2BA04F2862574BA007803B9)?

Comment: Joe, I can actually programmatically set a voltage, turn the instrument from remote to local control and the Bertan goes to the values I set programmatically. (I realized this after the original post)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you can use LabVIEW to set the values that you want, but the output won't update until you change the control mode from remote to local? If that's correct, how do you change the mode - from the instrument's front panel or from your PC commands?